# Wheel issues and steering wheel

Tags: wheels

So whenever I turn my vehicle either to full right or left does steering wheel does not return to center I have manually return. As well as the front tires are straight they are sitting at angle. The top is pushed and the bottom kicks out

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When was the last time you had an alignment done? Both of the things you have listed are directly affected by the alignment.

Comment: You should get the suspension bushes checked.

Comment: I haven’t done anything yet since I purchased recently from used dealership (Carmax). And thank you gentlemen for the info.

Comment: Take it back to carmax and suggest they fix any front end problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your wheel alignment is very badly off - as @Moab says, you should take it back and get the dealer to sort it.

The vertical angle of the tyres is called 'camber' - you've just described a very large amount of negative camber (top in, bottom out). The lack of self-centering is usually down to the 'toe' angle - how far in or out the front of the wheels point with the steering wheel straight.

Any decent tyre place will be able to look up the correct values of these for your car, and many will do the check for you for free, and give you a print-out of the current values.

The link in [This question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/54915/373) shows an example of an alignment printout

Comment: From just a glance I would almost 1inch  in attop part. Just fldropped it and I have feeling they’re going to get me oh your your extended warranty doesn’t cover these issues but dropped about 2hrs ago. Waiting for they’re call.

Comment: Just dropped it off they’re are going to fix for free and will be changing I forgot what is was but had to with the arms from the left side and right side. As well some of the frame they messed up. I actually had gone over 30 day policy but they were comprehensive and kind to help. Even though I have theyre point to point inspection from them saying the vehicle had no issue thanks a lot gentleman for your input. When i pick it up I am going to ask if they test drove it.